# Close your tags!

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, balanced-string, syntax

<sup><sup>This is based off a previous deleted challenge of mine with the same name</sup></sup>

#### Introduction

You are tasked with writing a program that returns a truthy or falsey value based on if the input has all its XML-like<sup>1</sup> tags appropriately opened and closed and in the right order. Consider the following as input:

```
<Apple>
```

This would return a falsey value because the tag is not closed correctly. This:

```
<Apple></Apple>
```

On the contrary returns a truthy value because it is closed correctly. The program should also check nested tags to make sure they are in the correct position. For example, take this as input:

```
<mango><Apple></mango></Apple>
```

All the tags are closed correctly, *but not in the correct order*. Your program must check for correct tag hierarchy and nesting.

#### Definitions

Let me define a few things before I get into the rules and assumptions.

**Tag**

A basic XML-style tag. For example: `<Apple>`. They can have at most, one leading and trailing space (or else it's invalid and falsey), so `< Apple >` and `<Apple>` are the same.  These tags can also contain attributes like `foo="bar"` *(with required double quotes, or else invalid and falsey)*, and the attribute name can only contain any alphanumeric character or `_`, `:`, `-`, and `.`. The attribute names also do not require an attribute value, and values can contain anything except `"` before the closing double quote. The closing tag must not contain attributes, and no tags should have newlines in them.

**Tag Name**

Tag names are the tags' names. For example, `<Apple>`'s tag name is `Apple`. Tag names can contain the same characters as attribute names, and are case-sensitive. This means `<Apple>` is **not** `<apple>`.

**Self-Closing Tag**

A regular tag that closes itself such as `<Apple />` or `<Apple/>` (they are the same). The space between the slash and the tag name is allowed.

**Plain Text**

A string of characters that can contain anything and are not enclosed in `<` and `>`.

**"Simple" Tag**

Either an opening, closing, or self-closing tag.

#### Rules

- Output may be returned or printed, and input may be taken any way you like
- Input is a string, consisting of either tags, plain text, or both
- Your program can be a function or a whole working program
- Plain text can be anywhere; if the input consists *only* of plain text, the program should return a truthy value.
- Recognition of nested tags is required for the program. If a tag is nested in a tag, that nested tag must be closed before the parent is closed, just like regular XML, or else a falsey value should be returned

#### Assumptions

- You can assume that input will always be one or more "simple" tag(s)
- You can assume that input will always follow the format for tags defined above

#### Test Cases

**Falsey**

```
<apple>

<apple></Apple>

<apple></mango>

<apple><mango>

<a><b></a></b>

Text<ul><li></li><ul />

<pear attr=foo></pear attr=foo>

<Ketchup flavor=spicy></Ketchup>

<Ap ple></Apple>
```

**Truthy**

```
Text 

<Apple />

<Apple></Apple>

< Apple ></ Apple>

<mango><Apple/></mango>

<mango>Text<div class="bar">More text \o/</div></mango>

<food group="fruit">Fruits:<orange :fruit-variety="clementine" /><pear _fruit.type="asian" /></food>

<example foo="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890-/:;()$&@.,?!'" noValue>Any characters allowed! (0.0)</example>
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins. [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/56456) are prohibited as usual.

---

<sup>1</sup>**Note**: This is not real XML, but a pseudo-XML with different rules for the challenge. Tag and attribute names differ from specification.

Comment: If a tag has more than one space before or after it, do we have to mark it false?

Comment: @JayDepp Yes - let me clarify that in my post

Comment: Can we use builtins that parse strings to XML?

Comment: @obarakon The problem is this isn't necessarily valid XML. See the footnote.

Comment: Is it correct to say, that this is a *truthy input*: `< : : :><:/><: :=":=:" ::></:>< /:>`?

Comment: @insertusernamehere Yes, that is truthy.

Comment: *The attribute names also do not require an attribute value* ? Example please?

Comment: @edc65 `<example attrWithoutVal></example>` just like `<input required>`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>76</s> 74 Bytes

```
+`< ?([-.:\w]+)( ?[-.:\w]+(="[^"]*")?)* ?(/>|>[^<>]*< ?/ ?\1 ?>)

^[^<>]*$
```

Since I've seen that retina is really good for golfing regexes, I figured I'd try it out. Follows the same logic as my Ruby answer and prints 0 or 1.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@dYKNgrxGtq2cVUx6rramhYA9ja9gqRccpxWopadpragHV6NvV2EXH2djFagF16CvYxxgq2NtpcnHFQQRV/v@3yU3MS8@3C0mtKLFJySxTSM5JLC62VUpKLFKy880vSlUoAcooxOTr2@gDpe1s9CHqAQ)

Comment: You don't need the `M\``. If the final stage only has a single part, match mode is implied.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby (2.3.1), <s>103</s> <s>101</s> 100 Bytes

```
->s{s.sub!(/< ?([-.:\w]+)( ?[-.:\w]+(="[^"]*")?)* ?(\/>|>[^<>]*< ?\/ ?\1 ?>)/,'')&&redo;!(s=~/<|>/)}
```

Anonymous function called by appending `.call("<Apple></Apple>")`. Substitutes matching or self closing tags until there arent any, and then returns whether the string has no angle brackets remaining.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#bVJdj9MwEHzPr3At1CblGvf4puc4VHAICSEkhHhpeshJnDbgxsZ22gaO@@tlk1yhd@Ih2czObHbGySHlOYoQpTfvLj9dvvn42qNcaynYsVIyv4c3vFqpf/gvZDQFFgpJmfdZ7B2tJaOyhEZ7qyUiINOCG8SdM1GhFFB3sUffC5eta40KybfKRFaXWQOy2zYI5hrd8XX07a2UgignSVoPqB0AXbd7fi8R6inooGOrT9MryUnYvnap8nKLMsmtjXDKDWYflBHItbsSRSgB@mSuaE2tjKp1hAtTlw6zt22xM6oMaASade3JlptSuCbCmRQbUbmyEhhM9@f1tdOErtEiwtyWvOo40r4dlog937RBAAKdZrkoVuvy23e5qZT@Yayrt7t98/P80eMnT589f/FyOiGzCz94MHwVnsWDEUaV@sJlLdi8alC25oZnThiLuJRqJ/IB8qfhNKDkds/JmXteEU2Y/WVDW6cDn1AU@4tJOEt2y4eBj@Ljsx/hxRVejnEQB2PQJIRds8UVZcsxjCQErnMUs4CcjUbBcGhEri4Gvo1uCL1mJPjteRrBnxpaLUvn46TCQbjh2h8WQVipSsTAt9//vwKIEXuHwx8)

Comment: This marks `<p title="This is a \"test\"."></p>` as Falsey, but it shouldn't be.

Comment: @orlp 'values can contain anything except " before the closing double quote.'

Comment: Oh it's not real XML...

Comment: Real XML should never be parsed with regex :)